# Serialize objects list to JSon without Parent object name

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have objets list and output them using code below in my MVC application.

```
 public JsonResult ConversionInfo(string srcFormat)
        {
            return Json(MetadataDbService.FindBySourceFormat(srcFormat).Select(m => new
            {
                m.ConversionMeta
            }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The code produce such result. Every line/item starts with parent object name `ConversionMeta` .

```
[
{"ConversionMeta":{"Id": "delete", "Name": "delete page from PDF", "Description": "You can delete any page from PDF blah blah...",…}},
{"ConversionMeta":{"Id": "delete", "Name": "delete page from PDF", "Description": "You can delete any page from PDF blah blah...",…}}
]
```

I would like to have such result, any ideas how to modify the code?

```
[
{"Id": "delete", "Name": "delete page from PDF", "Description": "You can delete any page from PDF blah blah...",…},
{"Id": "delete", "Name": "delete page from PDF", "Description": "You can delete any page from PDF blah blah...",…}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrapping your object in a wrapper object by selecting it using `new { }`.

Ditch the `new { }` wrapper, and select the `ConversionMeta` property itself.

```
public JsonResult ConversionInfo(string srcFormat)
{
    return Json(MetadataDbService.FindBySourceFormat(srcFormat).Select(m => m.ConversionMeta), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to create a class which contains all the properties and the serialize the class to json using JSON.NET

You can install JSON.NET via Nuget

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

The create a array of the class and fill it with all your entries

Then you can use the JsonConvert.SerialzeObject Method to create the Json

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConversionMeta[] conversionMetaArray = new ConversionMeta[3];
    conversionMetaArray[0] = new ConversionMeta()
    {
        Id = "deleted",
        Name = "delete page from PDF",
        Description = "You can delete any page from PDF blah blah..."
    };
    conversionMetaArray[1] = new ConversionMeta()
    {
        Id = "deleted",
        Name = "delete page from PDF",
        Description = "You can delete any page from PDF blah blah..."
    };
    conversionMetaArray[2] = new ConversionMeta()
    {
        Id = "deleted",
        Name = "delete page from PDF",
        Description = "You can delete any page from PDF blah blah..."
    };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(conversionMetaArray);
}
```

This is the class:

```
class ConversionMeta
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
[
{"Id":"deleted","Name":"delete page from PDF","Description":"You can delete any page from PDF blah blah..."},
{"Id":"deleted","Name":"delete page from PDF","Description":"You can delete any page from PDF blah blah..."},
{"Id":"deleted","Name":"delete page from PDF","Description":"You can delete any page from PDF blah blah..."}
]
```